# find controls that have been selected in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I'm building a web application for a client with some unique controls and criteria.  One page involves a detailed search function consisting of about 100 combo boxes and listboxes.  What I am trying to do is do a foreach(control that has been changed/selected){} and feed it into a function to generate a query.  There are 100 but the user may only use three for a particular search ?

I know there must be a way to do this.  Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Maybe you should have checkboxes which enable each criteria, that way you will know which ones have been "used."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use something like:

```
List<Control> list = new List<Control>();

public void ControlRecursive(Control Root)
    {
        if(typeof(ComboBox) == Root.GetType() && ((ComboBox)Root).Checked)
            list.Add(Root);
        else if (Root is RadListBox)
        {
            // deal with RadListBox here
        }
        // if all your other types
        // ...

        foreach (Control Ctl in Root.Controls)
            ControlRecursive(Ctl);
    }
```

Then call this with `ControlRecursive(form1);`

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do I was playing around with the idea of a java array, however I am shakey at best with java.  Let Me ask you a question.  I am using Telerick RadListBox I can't seem to get the typeof to recognize.  It works with a normal asp control, nay advice ?

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question, I don't know the answer to that, except to say that the RadListBox probably inherits from type ListBox, and you could check for that.  typeof() works on custom classes, so I really am not sure why that doesn't work.  If you need it specifically then start another question on how to use that if statement with that control.  Glad I could be of help with the loop.

Comment: I ended up using moving over to regular list boxes, the only reason I wanted to use the rad list boxes is because you can easily add a check-box which I feel is a little more user friendly.  Thanks again for the help

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna See edit, there is another way of checking for type that I just remembered.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a javascript function associated with onchange / select for each of your controls and then add to a javascript array the item that has been selected.  Then you can pass that array to your query generation to know what variables to pick up for your search.